# replace more than two consecutive empty lines by two empty lines

Tags: bash, sed

I am using bash and the would like to apply the changes directly in the file using a one-liner, so sed would be perfect.

I have tried using the option N of sed then searching for "\n{3,}" and replacing that with "\n\n" but that did not work...

```
sed -ri 'N;N;N;N;s/^(\n){3,}$/\n\n/' ./file
```

Moreover, this would not take into account all occurrences of the search pattern as it would have to call itself to work.

Comment: Can you clarify with some sample inputs and outputs?  As it is, I can't tell whether you want two blank lines (three newlines) or two newlines (one blank line) between paragraphs.  An example of what you expect would clear this up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^$/n;//!b;:a;N;s/\n$//;ta' file
```

If the current line is empty print it and refresh with the next line. If the current line is not empty print it and start again. If the current line is empty then remove any further empty lines until a non-empty line or the end of file.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I came up with the following:

```sed
/./n      # non-empty line; just print it as normal
N         # otherwise, append the next line
/^\n$/D   # and if it's also empty, delete the first line, and don't print yet
```

I'm using GNU sed, which doesn't exit when you use `N` at the end; for other implementations, you might need `$!N` instead.

You can easily adjust the maximum number of empty lines to allow, by adding more `\n` characters in the final command.

Here's a test, showing that it works at beginning, middle and end of a file:

```
$ echo $'\n\nabc\n\ndef\n\n\n\n\nabc\n\n\n' | sed -e '/./n;N;/^\n$/D'

abc

def

abc

$
```

Comment: This is nice work, but won't quite do what he asked (but maybe it is what he wanted tho). This is only leaving 1 blank line at the moment. This leaves two line feeds but only one blank line between each.

Comment: thebluefox, could you clarify, you asked for two blank lines,  did you mean 2 blank lines between other text (which would be 3 linefeeds - (1 on the end of the non-blank line + 2 at the ends of the two blank lines), or did you mean two linefeeds between lines, which would leave one blank line.

Comment: I misread "two blank lines" as "two newlines", sorry.  I *think* you can just add another newline to the pattern; checking now.

Comment: I think your implementation is actually exactly what he wanted though, because that's what he was trying to insert himself, just two linefeeds, so I think it is just a wording issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but if not, it should point you in the right direction:

```
sed -n '/./!H;/./{x;s/\n\{3,\}//p;x;p}'
```

If the line is empty, put it in hold space. If the line is not empty, exchange pattern and hold space, remove unwanted newlines and print the former hold space. Then fetch the non-empty line from hold space and print it.

Answer (score -1):

Sed can be hard to keep compatible, depending on your requirements. But, since you just wanted a one liner, perl will do the job and may be more portable

If you need two blank lines (3 linefeeds between text):

```
perl -p0777i -e 's/^\n{3,}/\n\n/; s/\n{4,}/\n\n\n/sg;'  yourfile.txt
```

If you need one blank lines (2 linefeeds between text):

```
perl -p0777i -e 's/^\n{2,}/\n/; s/\n{3,}/\n\n/sg;'  yourfile.txt
```

If you need one blank line, but no newlines at start of file:

```
perl -p0777i -e 's/^\n+//; s/\n{3,}/\n\n/sg;'  yourfile.txt
```

If you dont particularly care much about whether theres one or two blanks at the start of a file:

```
perl -p0777i -e 's/\n{3,}/\n\n/sg;'  yourfile.txt
```

test script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

test_contents()
{
  cat <<EOF



3 blank lines 3 linefeeds prior,  expect 1 removed
3 blank lines 4 linefeeds  after, expect 1 removed



1 blank line, 2 linefeeds after, expect no change

2 blank line, 3 linefeeds after, expect no change


5 blank lines, 6 linefeeds after, expect 3 removed





3 lines to end of file, expect 1 removed



EOF
}

before=$(mktemp -t test_before.XXXXXX)
after=$(mktemp -t test_after.XXXXXX)
sed_after=$(mktemp -t test_sed.XXXXXX)

test_contents > "${before}"
test_contents > "${after}"
test_contents > "${sed_after}"


perl -p0777i -e 's/^\n{3,}/\n\n/; s/\n{4,}/\n\n\n/sg;' "${after}"

echo Orig:
cat "${before}"
echo "Diff:"
diff -U1000 "${before}" "${after}"
```

What this does is:

```
   -p0777      read whole files in one go
   -i          edit files specified on commandline
   -e          specify the edit expression
```

The expression parameter /sg
Means:

```
  s - treat as a whole string including newlines
  g - keep applying the edits until no more can be done
```

output is:

```
+ diff -U1000 /tmp/test_before.XSRHYr /tmp/test_after.mU4hLU
--- /tmp/test_before.XSRHYr 2017-02-14 21:31:09.376110847 +1030
+++ /tmp/test_after.mU4hLU  2017-02-14 21:31:09.379110855 +1030
@@ -1,23 +1,17 @@


-
 3 blank lines 3 linefeeds prior,  expect 1 removed
 3 blank lines 4 linefeeds  after, expect 1 removed


-
 1 blank line, 2 linefeeds after, expect no change

 2 blank line, 3 linefeeds after, expect no change


 5 blank lines, 6 linefeeds after, expect 3 removed


-
-
-
 3 lines to end of file, expect 1 removed


-
```